# Error in bind function (C simply server)

Tags: c, bind

This is the code of my server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
//------------------------MAIN--------------------------//
{
int sock;       // sock descriptor
int new_sock;
int c;
int sin_size;
int koniec = 0;
char *ip_address;
char *port_number;
while (1)
        {
        static struct option OpcjeProgramu[] =
        {
        { "port", required_argument, 0, 'p'},
        { "interface", required_argument, 0, 'i'},
        { 0, 0,0,0 }
        };

int option_index = 0;


c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "p:i:", OpcjeProgramu, &option_index);

if ( c == -1 )
break;

switch(c)
        {
        case 0:
        if (OpcjeProgramu[option_index].flag != 0)
        break;
        printf ("Option $s", OpcjeProgramu[option_index].name);
               if (optarg)
                printf (" with argument %s", optarg);
                printf ("\n");

        break;

        case 'p':
        printf ("Port number: %s\n",optarg);
        port_number = strdup(optarg);
        //snprintf(port_number,ROZMIAR,"%s",optarg);

        break;

        case 'i':
        printf ("IP address: %s\n",optarg);
        ip_address = strdup(optarg);

        break;
        case '?':
        puts(" This program invoke with -p (--port), -i(interface).");
        puts(" \n Example: \n  topserver -1 127.0.0.1 --port=10001");
// getopt_long wyswietli informacje o bledzie
        break;

        default:
        abort();
        }
}

printf(" ip_address: %s\n",ip_address);
printf(" port_number: %s\n", port_number);

int port_nr;
port_nr = atoi(port_number);

struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;  // information about server
struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;  // information about client


memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serveraddr.sin_port = htons((u_short) port_nr);
serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(inet_addr(ip_address));


// Set up sock:
if( ( sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) ) < 0 )
{
        perror("Nie mozna utworzyc gniazdza");
        return 1;
}

printf("Sock is set up, handle=%d\n", sock);
if(bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr) < 0))
{
        perror(" Error.");
        close(sock);
        return 1;
}

puts("Sock is bound.\n");

puts("listen...\n");

listen(sock, 32767);
```

Unfortunately, when I run the program for example `./server -p 1234 - i 127.0.0.1`

The program returns:

```
Sock is set up, handle =3 
Error: Invalid argument
```

Why does my bind function not work?

In this program I have to invoke my program with options, so I'm using the `getopt()` library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misplaced the less-than sign. It should read:

```
if (bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
```